# Способы оформления предложений

Tags: пунктуация

Имеется предложение:
Так, в последнее время поступает много запросов по комплектующим, конечно, покупателю удобнее купить все в одном месте. 
Оно, как мне кажется, требует редактирования.
Как лучше сделать? Поставить двоеточие после "комплектующим":

Так, в последнее время поступает много запросов по комплектующим: конечно, покупателю удобнее купить все в одном месте.

Или, может быть, тире:

Так, в последнее время поступает много запросов по комплектующим - конечно, покупателю удобнее купить все в одном месте.

Или просто разбить на два:

Так, в последнее время поступает много запросов по комплектующим. Конечно, покупателю удобнее купить все в одном месте.

Буду благодарна за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Если покупатель приобретает готовое изделие вместе с комплектующими, то предложения связаны по смыслу, и тогда  эту связь следует обозначить с помощью двоеточия или тире.

Например: "Так, в последнее время поступает много запросов по комплектующим - конечно, покупателю удобнее купить все в одном месте".

Это БСП, в котором  следственно-причинные отношения дополнены значением присоединения.

Answer (score 0):

Ни тире, ни двоеточие здесь ни чем не оправданы. Поскольку тире и двоеточие здесь будут иметь пояснительный характер. Запятая, как в вашем предложении, передает перечисление, что разрывает связь с двумя предложениями из-за вводного слова.
Лучше: Так, в последнее время поступает много запросов по комплектующим; покупателю, ***конечно,*** удобнее купить все в одном месте.
Но опять-таки предложение стилистически небезупречно. Что такое "по комплектующим"?

Comment: комплектующие
КОМПЛЕКТУ́ЮЩИЕ -их; мн. Детали, необходимые для комплектования технического изделия.

Answer (score 0):

Разбить на два, естественно.

Comment: Спасибо.)))